# Check button click via boolean?

Tags: java, android, onclick, boolean

I'm trying to set an onClickListener inside a boolean.
if the user clicked the wrong answer, then NumberIncorrect++, and it will show up a dialog to let user chooses either user want to redo or skip. If the user selected redo, the dialog will close and let the user redo the question, if the user selected skip, the dialog will close and show a new question.

```
public boolean checkAnswer(double submittedAnswer) {
    boolean isCorrect;
    if (currentQuestion.getRanswer() == submittedAnswer) {
        NumCorrect++;
        isCorrect = true;
    } else {
        NumIncorrect++;
        isCorrect = false;
    }

    score = NumCorrect*10 - NumIncorrect*10;

    return isCorrect;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_Redo)
        NumIncorrect--;
    else if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_Skip)
        NumIncorrect--;
}
```

The problem here is when the user selected the wrong answer and keeps redo it multiple times, and after users finally selected the correct answer, all the wrong answer attempts will be count in NumIncorrect. I'm trying to avoid this situation so that I want to set an onClickListener to minus the Incorrect count if users click on the Redo button.

Answer (score 0):

```
binding.myView.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
    // do something here
});
```

If you use `findViewById()` soz just

```
myView.setOnClickListener...
```